# Excel VBA: How to capture MsgBox response

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to perform the following tasks:

- write the message "Are you awake?" and display a question mark
- capture the response in the integer variable intR, put intR value in cell A2
- If the response is Yes, then write in cell A1 "Hurray"
- If the response is No, then write a message box with the text "ZZZZZZZZ"
- If the response is Cancel, then exit the sub

  ```
  Sub EX3_1_6MsgBoxFunction()

  Dim intR As Integer
  Dim TxtRng As Range
  Dim stra As String
  Dim stra2 As String

  'Have the message box display the buttons Yes, No and Cancel


  intR = MsgBox("Are you awake ? ", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)
  intR = Range("a2")

  If intR = vbYes Then
  Range("a1") = "Hurray"

  'that means yes

  ElseIf intR = vbNo Then
  stra2 = MsgBox("ZZZZZZZZZZ")

  Else

  Range("a2") = intR


  End If

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: I do have my end sub at the end but I did not copied it :)

Comment: Your first error is `intR = Range("a2")` instead of `Range("a2").Value = intR`

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like this.....

```
Sub EX3_1_6MsgBoxFunction()
Dim Ans As VbMsgBoxResult

'Have the message box display the buttons Yes, No and Cancel
Ans = MsgBox("Are you awake ? ", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)

Select Case Ans
    Case vbYes
        Range("A1").Value = "Hurray"
        Range("A2").Value = "Yes"
    Case vbNo
        Range("A1").Value = "ZZZZZZZZZZ"
        Range("A2").Value = "No"
    Case Else
        Range("A1").Value = ""
        Range("A2").Value = "Calcel"
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You shouldn't prefix a variable name with `vb`, that's reserved for in-built constants

Comment: That makes sense. Actually there is no constant called vbAns but have edited the answer for clarity. Thanks for raising that issue. :)

Comment: No problem at all! It doesn't override a constant but if you had a huge project and you'd named a bunch of variables with the 'vb' prefix then you might be tricking someone into trying to find microsoft documentation for them or just getting generally mixed up.

Comment: @sktneer: Interesting `Dim Ans As VbMsgBoxResult`. Does it bring any benefit over `Integer`? (Except showing the intended use)

Comment: @PatrickHonorez This variable type is rarely used while it is there to get the answer returned by the msgbox. I used it for clarity and to show it's use. :)

Comment: This answer provides a solution which is a bit different from what Pablo meant, but it's good nonetheless. I like the use of  `VbMsgBoxResult`

Answer (score 2):

First of all welcome to StackOverflow. When you ask a question, please remember to specify where you have problems in your code.

> - write the message "Are you awake?" and display a question mark

If I understand correctly, you don't *just* want a question mark to be displayed, but a choice of 3 possibilities, which are given by the following MsgBox's mode:

```
    intR = MsgBox("Are you awake ? ", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)
```

This does display a `MsgBox` which **requires an answer**: "Yes" or "No" or "Cancel". It cannot be anything else which is why I removed the last bullet point in your question. [The *answer code* is then mapped on an integer](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/constants/msgbox_ret.php) `intR`, that is correct.

> - capture the response in the integer variable intR, put intR value in cell A2

As YowE3K pointed out, it should be `Range("a2").Value = intR`, not `intR = Range("a2")`

> - If the response is Yes, then write in cell A1 "Hurray"
> - If the response is No, then write a message box with the text "ZZZZZZZZ"
> - If the response is Cancel, then exit the sub

You can use a `Select Case` here: think about it as an `If` with more than 2 possibilities:

```
Select Case intR
    Case 6 '<- According to the link I provided vbYes = 6
        Range("a1") = "Hurray"
    Case 7 '<- According to the link I provided vbNo = 7
        MsgBox "ZZZZZZZZ"
    Case 2 '<- According to the link I provided vbCancel = 2
        Exit Sub
End Select
```

You can write vbYes, vbNo and vbCancel instead of the integer. As pointed out by another user, the code is probably more readable that way.

Comment: Watch out for magic numbers in your code, you shouldn't have `Case 6`, it should be `Case vbYes`, `Case vbNo` and `Case vbCancel`, much more readable

Comment: Lol what the hell, I had written a link to MSDN to explain that, but somehow didn't work.

Comment: Your edit doesn't fix the issue, it should be `Case vbYes` not `Case 6 'vbYes`

Comment: Is that an *issue*? Maybe it's less readable, but I don't see no problem with the code.

Comment: It's a glaring issue, you could have put any old numbers in there. What if you *thought* that vbYes was 7 so you put in `Case 7 ' vbYes`, someone coming in and looking at it wouldn't understand why the select case was exiting at the wrong point, they're clicking yes and that should *definitely* be 7. You can eliminate this by just putting `Case vbYes` which is the correct way to do it.

Comment: The point is to remove magic numbers and actually use the constants, which is important

Comment: I didn't put 7 just because I *thought* vbYes was 7 (besides I wrote 6 not 7): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: But why would you force yourself to look up every constant each time you wanted to use them? It's redundant. You shouldn't have to know them off the top of your head or look them up you should just use them in your code. It shouldn't be hard to convince you not to use magic numbers, it's obvious.

Comment: And you might be right this time but what if, like my example, you thought you could remember what one of the constants was so you just put in `7, vbYes` or what if  you made a typo and put it in? There's no reason to take those risks where you can just put in the name of the constant

Comment: I agree, I wouldn't use them in my program as well, but the op might find useful learn some things about `MsgBox`. That's about it :)

Comment: You're teaching the OP to use magic numbers and you're too proud to listen, I'll stop trying

Comment: Dude, I even edited the answer giving you credits, and saying you're right. If this is not listening, I don't know what is.

Comment: Your answer still reads `Case 6`, `Case 7` and `Case 2`, you're using magic numbers, it's bad programming, it's nothing to do with readability, you're doing it wrong

Answer (score 1):

Further to Noldor's answer, as a general rule, you shouldn't use Hungarian notation for your variable names, `intR` doesn't really tell you anything about what the variable is apart from it's type.

You should be able to infer the type from the context and the variable name should give you something more useful. I'd recommend rewriting your code like

```
Sub EX3_1_6MsgBoxFunction()
    Dim retVal As Integer

    'Ask the user whether they're awake
    retVal = MsgBox("Are you awake ? ", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)

    'Switch on their answer
    Select Case retVal
        Case vbYes
            Range("A2") = "Hurray"
        Case vbNo
            MsgBox "ZZZZZZZ"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Note that you don't need to assign MsgBox to a variable, you can just call it with an argument (in this case `"ZZZZZ"`) to prompt the user, this way you can eliminate your needless `stra2` and `stra`. You also don't need to explicitly `Exit Sub` because the code will naturally exit after the `Select Case` or `If` statements.